# R ggplot2 stacked bar fills one bar in wrong order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making stacked bar chart with 5 bars.  The fills are ordered as expected for 3 of the 5 bars, but in the 3rd bar, the stacked segments are displayed in the wrong order.  I'm not allowed to post an image, but in the 3rd bar, the segment that should be on the bottom of the bar is shown on the top.

Here's the code for a simplified example.  There is only one observation per combination of the x and fill variables in the example, but I still used the stat_summary function because I actually want to use the code for a data frame with thousands of observations.

What is wrong with this code, and how can I make all the bars display the fills in the correct order?

```
library(ggplot2)
str(d2)
d2
ggplot(data=d2, aes(x=x,y=y, fill=f) ) +  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", position="stack")
R.version
packageVersion("ggplot2")


> str(d2)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 5 levels "1CP","2PD","3AM",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ y: num  0.3456 0.0699 0.6659 0.7358 0.3456 ...
 $ f: Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "N1"<"N2"<"N3"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
> d2
        x          y  f
1     1CP 0.34556309 N1
20021 1CP 0.06985134 N2
25026 1CP 0.66592260 N3
30031 1CP 0.73577575 N4
2     2PD 0.34556309 N1
20022 2PD 2.37410008 N2
25027 2PD 0.74289404 N3
30032 2PD 0.35221355 N4
3     3AM 0.34556309 N1
20023 3AM 0.80074871 N2
25028 3AM 0.62036885 N3
30033 3AM 0.09105373 N4
4     4AP 0.34556309 N1
20024 4AP 0.35911943 N2
25029 4AP 0.12228402 N3
30034 4AP 0.18667499 N4
5     ALL 0.34556309 N1
20025 ALL 0.97839760 N2
25030 ALL 0.58666595 N3
30035 ALL 0.36948221 N4
> ggplot(data=d2, aes(x=x,y=y, fill=f) ) +  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", position="stack")
> R.version
           _                                           
platform       i386-pc-mingw32                             
arch           i386                                        
os             mingw32                                     
system         i386, mingw32                               
status         Patched                                     
major          2                                           
minor          15.1                                        
year           2012                                        
month          07                                          
day            04                                          
svn rev        59723                                       
language       R                                           
version.string R version 2.15.1 Patched (2012-07-04 r59723)
nickname       Roasted Marshmallows                        
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘0.9.1’
>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also reported this problem as a potential bug to the author of `ggplot2`, who provided this solution:

*I'm not sure if this is a bug or not - but you can get the desired behaviour by adding 
`order=f` to the ggplot function call.  I'm not sure why it's not defaulting to that.*

The suggested addition of `order=f` resolved the problem!